# How can I create specialized builders for semantic layout in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is how I'd like to write markup in say index.html.erb

```
<%= page_for "Super Cool Page" do |p| %>
    <%= p.header do %>
        Ruby is Cool
    <% end %>
    <%= p.body do %>
        Witty discourse on Ruby.
    <% end %>
    <% if page.has_sidebar? %>
        <%= p.sidebar do %>
            <ul><li>Option 1</li></ul>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which would output

```
<div class="page">
    <header><h1>Super Cool Page</h1></header>
    <section>
    Witty discourse on Ruby.
    </section>
</div>
```

and when page.has_sidebar? is true

```
<div class="page">
    <header><h1>Super Cool Page</h1></header>
    <asside><ul><li>Option 1</li></ul></asside>
    <section>
    Witty discourse on Ruby.
    </section>
</div>
```

I've taken a look at the `FormHelper` class in rails for guidance, but it seems like I'd have to duplicate a lot of work which I'm trying to avoid. I'm really just trying to figure out where to hang the classes/modules/methods in the framework and whit kind of object `|p|` should be.

My first inclination was to create a `PageBuilder` class that implements `header`, `body` and `sidebar` methods. But I got stuck on the rendering pipeline to get everything output just right.

Is there a gem that already provides this type of semantic generation? If not I'd love any insight on how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something similar in my templates.  Here's a modification.  This should work in Rails 3.

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  class PageBuilder
    def initialize(title, template)
      @title, @template = title, template
      @header, @body, @sidebar = nil, nil, nil
      @options = { :page => {} , :header => {}, :sidebar => {}, :body => {}, :title => {} } 
      @logger = Rails.logger
    end
    def parse(&block)
      if block_given?
        if @template.respond_to?(:is_haml?) && @template.is_haml?
          contents = @template.capture_haml(&block) 
        else
          #erb
          contents = @template.capture(&block)
        end
      else
        contents = ""
      end
      contents
    end

    def page (options,&block)
      options[:class] ||= "page"
      @options[:page] = options
      parse(&block)
      content = ""
      content += @template.content_tag(:title, @options[:title]) { @title } unless @title.nil?
      content += @template.content_tag(:header,@options[:header]) do
        @template.content_tag( :h1) { @header } 
      end unless @header.nil?
      content += @template.content_tag(:asside, @options[:sidebar]) { @sidebar } unless @sidebar.nil?
      content += @template.content_tag(:section, @options[:section]) { @body } unless @body.nil?
      return @template.content_tag(:div, @options[:page]) { content.html_safe }
    end
    def header(options={},&block)
      @options[:header] = options
      @header = parse(&block)
      nil
    end
    def sidebar(options={},&block)
      @options[:sidebar] = options
      @sidebar = parse(&block)
      nil
    end
    def body(options={},&block)
      @options[:body] = options
      @body = parse(&block)
      nil
    end
  end

  def page_for(title, options = {}, &block )
    raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
    builder = PageBuilder.new(title, view_context )
    return builder.page(options) do 
      block.call(builder)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, in your sample code, when `page.has_sidebar? == false`, you will get

```
<div class="page"><title>Super Cool Page</title><header><h1>
    Ruby is Cool
</h1></header><section>
    Witty discourse on Ruby.
</section></div>
```

and when `page.has_sidebar? == true`, you will get

```
<div class="page"><title>Super Cool Page</title><header><h1>
    Ruby is Cool
</h1></header><asside>
      <ul><li>Option 1</li></ul>
</asside><section>
    Witty discourse on Ruby.
</section></div>
```

You can rearrange stuff in the `page` method to get any desired layout as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but have you tried looking at Haml?

It has a much more succinct syntax so the example you suggested might be written as:

```
.page
  %header
    %h1 Super Cool Page
  %asside
    %ul
      %li Option 1
  %section
    Witty Discourse on Ruby
```

As you can see structure in Haml is provided using indentation which helps with reading
Haml source too.

If on the other hand you are attempting this as a learning exercise on how to build a template parser yourself then maybe look into the source of Haml or one of the other templating engines.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing can be achieved with [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for).

[Haml](https://github.com/nex3/haml) is supercool, [Slim](https://github.com/stonean/slim) could even be better?

Comment: Not interested in Haml or another syntax. I'm trying to enforce certain html tags and classes on elements of a page - some elements may appear more than once and in custom locations depending on the view. The various conditions make it unsuitable for content_for.

Comment: Helpers can do this kind of stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

I use a helper to process the args, which then calls the various partials to render.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a gem called [builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/). It may be able to provide the framework that you can build your example above upon.

Here's a rough attempt to implement the example you gave above:

```
require 'builder'
page = Page.new             # you'll have to implement this class
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>STDOUT, :indent=>2)
builder.div(:class => 'page') do |div|
  if page.has_header?
    div.header do |header|
      header.h1("Super Cool Page")
    end
  end
  div.body("whitty discourse on Ruby")
  if page.has_sidebar?
    div.sidebar do |side|
      side.ul do |ul|
        ul.li("Option 1")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which outputs:

```
<div class="page">
  <header>
    <h1>Super Cool Page</h1>
  </header>
  <body>whitty discourse on Ruby</body>
  <sidebar>
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
    </ul>
  </sidebar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a tiny DSL (*Domain Specific Language*) to do this. In fact, it is a good fit IMO. The code I wrote is not used exactly how you've shown in your question, though.

#### Usage

```
#Example 1:
def some_boolean_method?
  true
end

output = String.new
PageDsl.generate(output) do  #or, use STDOUT to output to console
  page_for do
    "Super Cool Page"
    header do
      "Ruby is Cool"
    end
    body do
      "Witty discourse on Ruby."
    end
    if some_boolean_method?
      sidebar do
        "<ul><li>Option 1</li></ul>"
      end
    end
  end
end

p output
# => "<div class='page'><header>Ruby is Cool</header><body>Witty discourse on Ruby.</body><section><ul><li>Option 1</li></ul></section></div>"


#Example 2:
PageDsl.generate(STDOUT) do
  some_cool_tag do
    "Super Cool Page"
    gak! do { :class=> "ff" }
      "Ruby is Cool"
    end
  end
end
# => <some_cool_tag><gak!>Ruby is Cool</gak!></some_cool_tag>
```

#### Implementation

```
class PageDsl
  def initialize(output)
    @output = output
  end

  def content(text)
    @output << text.to_s
    nil
  end

  def translate_semantic_tag(tagname,attributes={})
    newline = "" # "\r\n" uncomment to add newlines
    case tagname.to_sym
    when :page_for
      tagname = "div"
      attributes[:class] =  "page"
    when :header
      tagname = "header"
    when :body
      tagname = "section"
    when :sidebar
      tagname = "asside"
    end

    @output << "<#{tagname}"
    attributes.each { |attr,value| @output << " #{attr}='#{value}'" }
    if block_given?
      @output << ">" << newline
      content = yield
      if content
        @output << content.to_s << newline
      end
      @output << "</#{tagname}>" << newline
    else
      @output << "/>" << newline
    end
    nil
  end
  alias method_missing translate_semantic_tag

  def self.generate(output, &block)
    PageDsl.new(output).instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

Note, the implementation does not do nesting, for example `<header><h1>..</h1></header>`, but that should be simple to implement.